# Polling a local folder and sending files to FTP using Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm using spring integration output channel to send files to FTP server(s), from the researches I did, I was able to send one file from a folder to the ftp, my concern is that I want to keep on polling a local folder ex: BEY/finalBEY.csv and once there is a file with this name "finalBEY.csv" I want to send it to a certain FTP server and if there is no file in the folder I want to keep on watching or polling the folder until there is a one, I'm sure this is possible but not able to find the solution or the proper coding, thanks for helping

Code I used:

```
    public IntegrationFlow ftpOutboundFlow(Branch myBranch){
    return IntegrationFlows.from(OUTBOUND_CHANNEL)
            .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(true)

                    //.remoteFileSeparator("/")
                    .fileNameExpression("headers['" + FileHeaders.FILENAME + "']")

                    //.fileNameExpression("BEY/FEFOexportBEY.csv")
                    .remoteDirectory(myBranch.getFolderPath()))

            .get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel OUTBOUND_CHANNEL(){
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}

@MessagingGateway
public interface MyGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = OUTBOUND_CHANNEL)
    void sendToFtp(File file);

}
```

In the controller where I'm registering the flow and sending a file.

```
private void addFlowftpOutbound(String name) {
        branch = branchService.getById(Long.valueOf(name));
        System.out.println(branch.getBranchCode());
        IntegrationFlow flow = ftIntegration.ftpOutboundFlow(branch);
        this.flowContext.registration(flow).id(name +"o").register();
        myGateway.sendToFtp(new File("BEY/finalBEY.csv"));
    }
```

Consol trial output:

When no file in BEY folder, which is logical.

```
2018-11-27 08:32:47.793  WARN 6420 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] o.s.i.ftp.session.FtpRemoteFileTemplate  : File BEY\finalBEY.csv does not exist
```

After dropping finalBEY.csv in the folder, the inbound flow just reading what is new there in the folder and as you can see nothing is sent, as well I checked the ftp server and nothing is there, note that if the file is already there when I run the app, definitely it will send it, this is already tested.

```
2018-11-27 08:33:17.985  INFO 6420 --- [ask-scheduler-2] f.s.s.configuration.FTIntegration        : flow=stockInboundFlowFromAFT, message=incoming file: BEY\finalBEY.csv
2018-11-27 08:33:17.985  INFO 6420 --- [ask-scheduler-2] f.s.s.configuration.FTIntegration        : flow=stockIntermediateStageChannel, message=rename file: BEY\finalBEY.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are polling the directory yourself (and using a gateway). Simply ignore files where the `final` file does not exist.

You can use a polled `FileReadingMessageSource` to poll the directory and implement a custom `FileListFilter`.

The custom filter should filter out files where the `final` file does not yet exist.

Comment: Great I will try that and give a feedback, so if I see finalBEY.csv in the folder, I'm sending it to ftp, can I delete it after sending so that I wait for new file with same name and send the new one again? When you say final, is this a property that I need to invoke or this is something that I should implement in FileListerFilter ?Is there an exercise I can take look at?Thanks@Gary Russell

Comment: Sorry - I thought you meant you send `foo.csv` and only want to process it when `finalFoo.csv` is there too. For that you would need a custom filter. If you are just looking for a single file, the standard pattern filter will work for you. However, you need to be careful not to process the file while it is still being written. That is usually done by sending a second file or writing it with a different name and rename it when the writing is complete.

Comment: Not a problem, so if you remember on the first part that you helped me with when pulling csv files from ftp with name FEFOExportBEY.csv I'm processing this file and generating a new file naming it finalBEY.csv, this one I want to send it back to FTP server and remove it from local and the original file I want to archive it for historic reasons, for the writing of the file, might use like what I did in inbound writing with dif ext.and then changing it to csv, is there an example to look at that might contain some of those solutions and will manage trying to accomplish the rest?@Gary Russell

Comment: The `FileWritingMessageHandler` does exactly that by default - writes the file as `foo.txt.writing` and then renames it to `foo.txt` afterwards.

Comment: I'm trying to see if my coding is working as needed,I removed finalBEY.csv from the folder and ran the app (same code as above). To make sure that I'm polling the directory I dropped a file in the folder BEY with name finalBEY.csv but the app did not pick it up and sent it to ftp, I think i'm missing something here...maybe something is set to read one time from the folder? not sure :S ..I'm editing the code to show the consol output of this trial@Gary Russell

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-inbound). `You can use the local-filter attribute to configure the behavior of the local file system filter. Starting with version 4.3.8, a FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter is configured by default. ` It should allow a changed file to pass; earlier versions used an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`.

Comment: After checking this attribute, I can see that this is used on the inbound adaptor when bringing files to my local, I'm using the outbound adaptor to send finalBEY.csv to FTP once this csv is available, so I would be monitoring my local folder for finalBEY.csv to send it, thought the outbound could be done easier than the inbound :) seems harder to me, excuse me as I'm still new to spring integration and learning a lot of useful stuff, if I can get this outbound to monitor local folder example BEY/ that contains finalBEY.csv then would be top-notch to me...still struggling on that@Gary Russell

Comment: This discussion is getting too long; the admins here don't like lots of comments; I suggest you start a new question, show ALL the code involved (in and out) and explain exactly what you are struggling with.